# How to increment filename in php to prevent duplicates

Tags: php

In many situations, we need to make the filename different on the server when creating them to prevent duplication. And the most common answer to that seems to be, append the timestamp at the end or store the filename in the db and use those stored values to compute new name. These are good and all, but, appending a long time-stamp isn't always very user-friendly, and storing in the db isn't always an option. So, how can we auto-increment a standard filename while creating it via php?

Answer (score 7):

All these answers seem overkill:

```
$k = 0;
while(!$result){
    if(!file_exists("file[$k].ext"))
        $result = "file[$k].ext";
    $k++;
}
makefile($result);
```

Comment: This is a good start for how the concept code might work, but it assumes that all of the filenames are bracketed with the same file[#].ext filename. Jade Steffen's code / answer works with any filename.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple function I wrote for this purpose:

```
function incrementFileName($file_path,$filename){
 if(count(glob($file_path.$filename))>0)
 {
     $file_ext = end(explode(".", $filename));
     $file_name = str_replace(('.'.$file_ext),"",$filename);
     $newfilename = $file_name.'_'.count(glob($file_path."$file_name*.$file_ext")).'.'.$file_ext;
     return $newfilename;
  }
  else
  {
     return $filename;
  }
}
```

USAGE:

```
$newName = incrementFileName( "uploads/", $_FILES["my_file"]["name"] );
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["my_file"]["tmp_name"],"uploads/".$newName);
```

Comment: The count doesn't necessarily represent the biggest number. Quite the contrary, it will rather point to the existing file. The function should find the biggest number and increment it

Comment: This isn't robust. Given a dir with `foo.bar` and `foo_2.bar`, and an input of `foo.bar` for filename, this would return `foo_2.bar`. Additionally, the `str_replace()` call removes all occurences of `".$file_ext"`, not just the last one.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a short code snippet that demonstrates how you might start solving this problem.

```
// handle filename collision:
if(file_exists($newFile)) {
    // store extension and file name
    $extension = pathinfo($newFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $filename = pathinfo($newFile, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

    // Start at dup 1, and keep iterating until we find open dup number
    $duplicateCounter = 1;
    // build a possible file name and see if it is available
    while(file_exists($iterativeFileName =
                        $newPath ."/". $filename ."_". $duplicateCounter .".". $extension)) {
        $duplicateCounter++;
    }

    $newFile = $iterativeFileName;
}

// If we get here, either we've avoided the if statement altogether, and no new name is necessary..
// Or we have landed on a new file name that is available for our use.
// In either case, it is now safe to create a file with the name $newFile
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for the code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its [long-term value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by describing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: This should be the selected answer. It worked great with just a little modification for my use case. Great answer and saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

```
function incrementFileName($file_path,$filename){
  $array = explode(".", $filename);
  $file_ext = end($array);
  $root_name = str_replace(('.'.$file_ext),"",$filename);
  $file = $file_path.$filename;
  $i = 1;
  while(file_exists($file)){
    $file = $file_path.$root_name.$i.'.'.$file_ext;
    $i++;
  }
  return $file;
}
```