# How do I create a new text file with a new name from a phpscript everytime it is executed in php?

Tags: php

I am creating a program where the user by executing the code gets a new text file everytime.I have code for now  where i  can create text files to a certain number that is set by the limit of the variable.But i am trying to create a code where the program keeps creating  new textfiles untill the user stops creating them. For example textfile1.txt, textfile2.txt.And also strictly using php files and texfiles because that was the task that was given to me to create a survey so users can create as much as surveys as they want.

```
$number = $number + 10000;/ the number is where i am stuck at
//As you can see the number is set  and has limit now if this limit could be set by the count and amount of times the user creates a new textfile.txt  that would have numerrically it's own value i woudn't a problem
$filename = "textfile.txt".$number;
fopen($filename,"a");
```

Comment: I'm unclear what bit of this you are stuck with, but is suspect this is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633242/how-to-increment-filename-in-php-to-prevent-duplicates

Comment: Well there are many possible solutions to this problem, brother.

Comment: @Krishanu can u give any examples?

Comment: You can use timestamp for users. At least that's what i used, when i was working on something similar

Comment: The main aim is to get unique filename

Comment: @Krishanu yes sir but there is a problem i already have these type of ways but the question is how can u read these files with number files it is easy to read them from a differant from a differant php file because like i said i need to create a quiz

Comment: so you want to read files by the number?

Comment: no the idea is very simple is to create east text file names so that  the same they are created the same way you could read them from a differant file for example file1.txt, file2.txt is very easy to read from other php files

Comment: @NiloStick Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be tested by others. Explain in detail how you create the files and how you want to name them. Include a directory listing to explain what kind of files you want to create, how they are named and in which directories they are.